# How do I wrap boilerplate code in potentially a lambda when the return type is different every time?

Tags: java, lambda

I'll preface it by saying the return type could by anything, it can be a string, a primitive, but it could also be classes I created.

How can I have the following code broken down to a single line with different return types:

```
public static List<String> getSomething()
{
    // boilerplate code.
    try {
        // boilerplate code.
        return List.of("1", "2", "3");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // boilerplate code
    }
}

public static List<Integer> getSomething()
{
    // boilerplate code.
    try {
        // boilerplate code.
        return List.of(1, 2, 3);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // boilerplate code
    }
}
```

So that I could just have `return List.of(...)` or even just something as simple `return new Object()`, etc.

Comment: Maybe something like `public static <T> T getSomething(Supplier<T> codeToBeWrapped, Supplier<T> codeOnException) { try { return codeToBeWrapped.get(); } catch(Exception e) { return codeOnException.get(); } }` ... now, if the lambdas are too big, it may be worse.

Comment: That was the challenge I was running to. Ideally I'd love it to be just one like, that is just the return List.of(1, 2, 3); for example. So maybe something like () -> return List.of(1, 2, 3); It could even be something like return wrapperMethod(() -> return List.of(1, 2, 3)); but the question is what does wrapperMethod(lambda) return?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some context, but it seems it'll return whatever the supplier provides, `T` (the generic type) in my previous code. For `() -> List.of(1, 2, 3)` it would be equivalent to `List<Integer>` (again, `T` handles it), for `() -> List.of("a", "b", "c")` it would be equivalent to `List<String>`

Comment: It's not even a list all the time. It could be anything. It could be custom classes. Think of it as similar to a service where you make a call to something to get some data back where the data could be of any type.

Comment: Please post runnable code that explains your current situation better. Also, please tell us what you expect the outcome to be.

Comment: Is `boilerplate code` always the same, regardless of the exact type you return?

Comment: Boilerplate code is almost always the same.

Comment: Your 2 different snippets simply aren't the same. Hence, what you want here is trivially impossible. I'm not quite sure you think it's doable because you think `"1"` and `1` are kinda the same (in java, they just aren't), or if that was simply an example, and it's too oversimplified. Your question doesn't make sense unless you explain what the source is. _Possibly_ the answer involves `public static <T> List<T> getSomething(Source<T> sourceOfTs) { ... }`.

Comment: If I'm interpreting the question correctly, the first comment that @lealceldeiro made does what you want, more or less. You would use it like this: `getSomething(() -> List.of(1, 2, 3), () -> throw new RuntimeException())` or `getSomething(() -> List.of("a", "b", "c"), () -> throw new RuntimeException())` or `getSomething(() -> new Object(), () -> throw new RuntimeException())`. It's a bit hard to read in comment form vs. a formatted answer. It takes a second lambda for the exception handling because your original code doesn't show how exceptions are handled.

Comment: Also, if the boilerplate is "almost always the same" but not 100% always the same, then there needs to be some way to handle when it's different. If you can expand the code to a fully-working example, someone should be able to write a good answer for you. Please see [mre].

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what `boilerplate code` does, so this is only a general approach. Use an abstraction for the execution of the different parts of boilerplate. The main `getSomething()` method will be somewhat like this:

```
public static <T> T getSomething(Runnable boilerplate1, Runnable boilerplate2, Supplier<T> supplier, Runnable boilerplate3) {
  boilerplate1.run();
  try {
    boilerplate2.run();
    return supplier.get();
  } catch (Exception exc) {
    boilerplate3.run();
    //or other handling
    throw new RuntimeException(exc);
  }
}
```

Provide an overload with less parameters for the most cases (same boilerplate):

```
public static <T> T getSomething(Supplier<T> supplier) {
  Runnable boilerplate1 = () -> {
    //do stuff
  };
  Runnable boilerplate2 = () -> {
    //do stuff
  };
  Runnable boilerplate3 = () -> {
    //do stuff
  };
  return getSomething(boilerplate1, boilerplate2, supplier, boilerplate3);
}
```

Usage:

```
List<String> strings = getSomething(() -> List.of("1", "2", "3"));
List<Integer> integers = getSomething(() -> List.of(1, 2, 3));
```

It was already mentioned in comments, but if boilerplate code is really big, lambdas might actually hurt readability. In this case normal classes implementing Runnable (or other interface, if this one does not match your needs) may be better.